# iOS8: Programmatically scan for iPhones (or other smartphones) with bluetooth on in the area

Tags: ios, bluetooth, area, network-scan

I want to make an app and part of the app will require the user's iPhone to scan for other iPhones (or other smartphones) with bluetooth in the area and collect their name.

Is this possible on iOS and how much power does bluetooth take? Will my app not get approved?

Edit: I tried to turn my sister's iPhone 5's bluetooth on and I did not see her on my iPhone when I was trying to discover. I saw her on my Mac though.

I am not trying to pair, just see the name.

Comment: You will need an app running on both devices, not just one. The app will need to simultaneously advertise and listen for advertisements

Comment: Hmmm, I was thinking that the person who has his bluetooth on (Not paired to anything) just so people can discover his phone would not have any significant power problems because bluetooth is essentially 'inactive'... I tried this on my phone I experienced maybe 3% power decrease. I don't understand why this person necessarily needs the app because they can just turn on their bluetooth via iPhone settings?

Comment: Because an app on iOS can only discover BLE peripherals using Core Bluetooth - you need an app to act as a peripheral.  An app cannot discover the "phone" on it's own.